# Pass the parameters in the HTML URL to php

Tags: php, html, http-get

So I have a `html` file and a `php` file and what I am trying to do is to pass the values in the html `URL` parameters to my `php`.

So for example if the URL was `localhost\files\reset_username.html?args=erft5467uio$d` - then the `erft5467uio$d` bit should be captured in the `$_GET('args')` in my `php`. Problem is this value is not being passed onto the `php` file itself.

This is `html` file:

```
<html>
    <form id='setUsername' action='setnewusername.php' method='post'>
    <label for='username' >New Username: </label>
    <input type='text' name='usernameInput' id='username'  />
    <label for='newUsername' >Confirm Username: </label>
    <input type='text' name='newUsernameInput' id='newUsername' />
    <input type='text' name='Submit' value='Change Username' />
    </form>
</html>
```

This is my `php` code:

```
<?php
require "init.php";

if(!empty($_GET['args']) && !empty($_GET['usernameInput'])){
    $paramOne = $_GET['args'];
    $paramTwo = $_GET['usernameInput'];
    echo $paramOne;
    echo $paramTwo;
} 
else{
    echo "The args was not received";
}

?>
```

When I was testing my code, the php prints `"The args was not received"`. This means that the value `erft5467uio$d` was not passed.

How do I pass such values to the `php` script?

**EDIT:**
Every time a user requests to have their username changed they receive a link with a unique `args` value. In this case, the user receives an email with the link `localhost\files\reset_username.html?args=erft5467uio$d` in this case to their email. When they click on the link they are directed to the html page. Upon filling  out the form, the code `erft5467uio$d` as well as the `usernameInput` has to be passed to the php

Thanks

Comment: *ahem* => `method='post'`

Comment: As Fred noted, you should use `$_POST['args']`. Usually `$_GET` requests are used by `<a href="url/to/file?args=data">link</a>`

Comment: ...or `method='get'` or pass it in your `action='setnewusername.php'` as an additional argument. `action='setnewusername.php?arg...'`

Comment: A GET argument in a request to a html file will _never_ reach a php script, unless you configured your http server in a very strange way.

Comment: Yeah but the user receives an email with the link `localhost\files\reset_username.html?args=erft5467uio$d` in this case to their email. When they click on the link they are directed to the html page. Upon filling it out the code `erft5467uio$d` has to be passed to the `php`

Comment: Then you need to retrieve the query string parameters from the email link and add them to your form as hidden inputs. This will probably require changing from a .html to a .php page. That, or some sort of JavaScript storage.

Comment: The email should contain GET arrays, yes. It doesn't matter how your PHP is processed "here" (however the method/arrays need to match), it's "how" it's processed "after" to GET it. So use a post method for user input and POST arrays and GET it after. If they match, great. However what's unclear is the `$d` here. Is that part of something else as a variable, or should that just be part of a "string"?

Comment: What you need to understand, is that when you declared the method to be POST, you also have to get it as POST. You cannot have the method as POST and get it as GET. Either you change the method to GET, and then get it as GET, or keep your method as POST, and get it as POST. Either way, you have to change one of them for it to work.

Comment: always the easiest way to check out whats going on is to add a simple var_dump($_REQUEST); and you will see if the arg is sent at all

Comment: Could someone please if they couldn't mind ,modify my code.

Comment: `http://localhost/files/setnewusername.php?args=erft5467uio` and not `reset_username.html` and a GET method not `method='post'`

Comment: How is that supposed to work when I need to put the html stuff in the file too?

Comment: this is so so confusing - even I have mind blown myself. its like I just did some black magic on myself - I just cant see how this will work now

Comment: @CodeMan I realize it could be confusing and I hope that the answer I posted below will help clear things up.

Answer (score 0):

*Foreword:* I don't see why you're using an `href` **and** a form for this.

If you want this to work, I suggest you go through what I wrote in the following, and please go through it carefully as it is rather long.

Sidenote: I would like to note that you were using the wrong type for your submit button, being `text` instead of `submit`.

```
<input type='text' name='Submit' value='Change Username' />
```

which should have read as:

```
<input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Change Username' />
```

First your form/PHP: (I removed out a few lines which no longer apply).

**form.html** (example filename)

```
<html>
    <form id='setUsername' action='setnewusername.php' method='post'>
    <label for='username' >New Username: </label>
    <input type='text' name='usernameInput' id='username'  />
    <label for='newUsername' >Confirm Username: </label>
    <input type='text' name='newUsernameInput' id='newUsername' />
    <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Change Username' />
    </form>
</html>
```

If you want to pass an argument, then what gets sent to the user via email would be a URL with the parameters.

NOTA: Go through some of the comments throughout the codes.

**setnewusername.php**

**N.B.:** If you want to use the value for `<input type='text' name='newUsernameInput' id='newUsername' />` then you will need to add it to the PHP. I am unsure how you want to use that.

```
<?php
 require "init.php";

 if( isset($_POST['Submit']) && !empty($_POST['usernameInput']) ){

    $username = $_POST['usernameInput'];
    echo $username;

$user = "erft5467uio"; // This is probably what should be taken from one of your inputs.

$to = "your_email@example.com";
$subject = "Your subject here";
$from_email = "email@example.com";

$message = "

Dear $username,

Visit the following site to verify your account changes:

http://www.example.com/from_mail.php?args=$user&usernameInput=$username

";

$headers = "From: $username <$from_email>\r\n";

/* or use the below
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
*/


mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 
// mail() or your own mailer
} 
else{
    echo "The args was not received.";
}

?>
```

The example from above `http://www.example.com/from_mail.php?args=$user&usernameInput=$username` will generate something like the following once sent:

http://www.example.com/from_mail.php?args=john&usernameInput=BigBadJohn

Then in your next file **from_mail.php** from above argument passed (the one that will fire up once the user clicks on the link you sent, you would then do:

```
<?php
require "init.php";

 if(!empty($_GET['args']) && !empty($_GET['usernameInput'])){

    $paramOne = $_GET['args'];
    $paramTwo = $_GET['usernameInput'];
    echo $paramOne;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $paramTwo;

// do something else here such as db insertion etc.
} 
else{
    echo "The args was not received";
}

?>
```

---

**Footnotes:**

- I hope this serves you well. If I missed something, let me know and I'll do my best to help out.

Final note:

I don't know what the `$d` in `erft5467uio$d` is for, therefore I didn't know what to do.